# How to test a custom hook event with Enzyme and Jest? (useKeyPress)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

**How to test a custom hook event with Enzyme and Jest? (useKeyPress)**

My current custom hook: (get keyboard user event and update keyPress)

```js
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const useKeyPress = () => {
    const [keyPress, setKeyPress] = useState('');

    // If pressed key is our target key then set to true

  const downHandler = (event) => {
      setKeyPress(event.code);
   }

  const upHandler = () => {
      setKeyPress('');
  };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
    
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
          window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
        };
    }, [])

    return ([keyPress]);
}

export default useKeyPress;
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Test the outcome of the keydown. Like a UI change on the front-end, if a UI change does happen on a keydown event. If you are open to using another testing lib. Try out react testing library with this awesome user-event addon lib. It's pretty much designed for writing such tests. https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank's @Tom, I found a solution with the react testing library.

```js
import useKeyPress from './../../src/component/useKeyPress/useKeyPress';
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import {fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'


test('Fire Enter keyboard event', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook((() => useKeyPress()))

    act(() => {
        fireEvent.keyDown(window, { key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter' });
    })
    expect(result.current.keyPress).toBe('Enter');
});
```